# Best way to query Django ORM to sum items by category per year (for time series)

Tags: python, sql, django, orm

Assume we have the models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
  description = models.CharField(...)  # Ex: 'horror', 'classic', 'self-help', etc.


class Book(models.Model):
  category = models.ForeignKey(Category, ...)
  written_date = models.DateField(...)
```

I want to make a query that will eventually get me the total number of books per category per year! Like so:

```
{
  '2019-01-01': { 'horror': 2, 'classic': 1},
  '2020-01-01': { 'horror': 2, 'classic': 1, 'self-help': 4},
  ...
}
```

I was only able to come up with the following query:

```
Book.objects \
.annotate(year=TruncYear('written_date')) \
.values('year', 'category__description') \
.order_by('year') \
.annotate(total=Count('id'))
```

However this only gets me

```
{
    {
        "category__description": "Horror",
        "year": "2019-01-01",
        "total": 2
    },
    {
        "category__description": "Classic",
        "year": "2019-01-01",
        "total": 1
    },
    {
        "category__description": "Horror",
        "year": "2020-01-01",
        "total": 2
    },
    ...
}
```

Is there any way to do this via ORM? Or I have to do this by manipulating the result directly? Thanks!

Comment: Don't really believe there's any ORM solution (In fact even if you look at SQL, you would only get tabular results). You can perform grouping in views (Willem's solution), grouping in the template using [`regroup` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup), or giving the illusion of a grouping using [`ifchanged` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged). I would suggest going with Willem's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can post-process the result with [**`groupby`** [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

data = Book.objects.values(
    'category__description'
    year=TruncYear('written_date'),
).annotate(
    total=Count('id')
).order_by('year', 'category__description')

result = {
    yrs: {r['category__description']: r['total'] for r in rs}
    for yrs, rs in groupby(data, itemgetter('year'))
}
```

Comment: this works! Will accept if there's no better ORM route in a couple days